# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) after to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastlane

I am using fastlane library, when I am trying to complete a submission I received a "stack level too deep" after this to_json here.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb#L985
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/base.rb#L66

My crash log

https://gist.github.com/bolom/95c9ce228fd14a8cf2f2524261e718ec

I am using 
ruby '2.4.1'
rails', '5.1.4
fastlane 2.70.3

How can I solve this problem?